# Create a custom stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I can load data in a `Stream<String>`.
I'm using a Stream because i cannot load all the data in memory, so **no collection allowed**.
I want to build a `Stream<MyClass>` to perform some operations on the objects of `MyClass`, feeding the stream with the `Stream<String>`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I'd say to call `inputStream.map(string -> toMyClass(string))` and you have a stream of MyClass objects. But that is probably not what your are looking for, I guess. What's your actual problem?

Comment: I don't get it, can't you simply do a `map` and pass the `Stream<MyClass>` along? And let it deal on the side where you pass it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you already have a `Stream<String>` and assuming there's something like a `MyClass(String)` constructor, just write:

```
Stream<MyClass> stream = stringStream.map(MyClass::new);
```

Answer (score -2):

**Java Example: Filtering Collection without using Stream**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


class Book{

    int book_id;
    String book_name;
    float price;

    public Book() {

    }

    public Book(int book_id, String book_name, float price) {
        this.book_id = book_id;
        this.book_name = book_name;
        this.price = price;
    }
}

public class Mystringstream {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     List<Book> booklist= new ArrayList<Book>();
     booklist.add(new Book(101,"java",500.25f));
     booklist.add(new Book(102,"php",300.20f));
     booklist.add(new Book(103,"c",400.34f));

     List<Float> bookpricelist=new ArrayList<Float>();
     for(Book book:booklist){
         if(book.price<500){
             bookpricelist.add(book.price);

         }
     }
        System.out.println("Filter Book Price List: "+bookpricelist);
    }
}
```

**output:**

Filter Book Price List: [300.2, 400.34]

**Java Stream Example: Filtering Collection by using Stream**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;


class Book{
    int book_id;
    String book_name;
    float price;

    public Book() {

    }

    public Book(int book_id, String book_name, float price) {
        this.book_id = book_id;
        this.book_name = book_name;
        this.price = price;
    }
}

public class Mystringstream {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     List<Book> booklist= new ArrayList<Book>();
     booklist.add(new Book(101,"java",500.25f));
     booklist.add(new Book(102,"php",300.20f));
     booklist.add(new Book(103,"c",400.34f));

     List<Float> bookpricelist=booklist.stream().filter(p->p.price < 500).map(p->p.price).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println("Filter Book Price List: "+bookpricelist);

    }
}
```

**output :**
Filter Book Price List: [300.2, 400.34]

Comment: Did not answer my question